# ES6 getters and setters weird behavior

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm confused with ES6 getters and setters. Could you explain what's going on here and why i get stack overflow.

I run this on Node.JS v5.1.1

```
'use strict';

class List {
  constructor(next, val) {
    this.next = next;
    this.val = val;
  }

  set val(v) {
    this.val = v;
  }

  get val() {
    return this.name;
  }
}


let res = new List(null, 1);
res.val = 3;
console.log(res);
```

Here's the output:

```
/Users/o/code/test/test.js:9
set val(v) {
       ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Comment: Yes, thanks you! Now i get this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are setting `this.val` again in **val setter**, which is causing **infinite recursion** by calling the setter again, just replace `this.val` with `this._val`. This will solve the issue :)

```
class List {
  constructor(next, val) {
    this.next = next;
    this._val = val;
  }

  set val(v) {
    this._val = v;
  }

  get val() {
    return this.name;
  }
}
```

Comment: i think the value should be private, otherwise there's little point in a setter...

Comment: Well, there's one more case also, if you want to perform some calculation before setting a public property, then setter might be used. However you are right, a private property should be used in most of the cases.

Comment: i was thinking that without a transformation of the incoming value, the only reason a setter would be used is to create a read-only property that doesn't lose track of the attempted sets, but that has a limited use-case...

Comment: Thank you, i've kinda got it.